# Create or Update (with PUT) in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a model which has has an primary key `id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)`.

When a `PUT` request is sent to the resource's endpoint `/api/v1/resource/<id>.json` I would like to *create* a new resource with the supplied `id` if the resource does not already exist.

*Note: I'm using a `ModelViewSet` with a `ModelSerializer`*

What is the most elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up overriding the `get_object()` method in my `ModelViewSet`:

```
class ResourceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This endpoint provides `create`, `retrieve`, `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Resource.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResourceSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            resource = Resource.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).first()
            if resource:
                return resource
            else:
                return Resource(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        else:
            return super(ResourceViewSet, self).get_object()
```

Perhaps there's a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: The issue with this is that it doesn't check for the create permission. I believe you should inherit from this mixin: https://gist.github.com/tomchristie/a2ace4577eff2c603b1b