# How to ensure idempotency in a Django REST API?

Tags: django, rest, api, architecture, idempotent

Say, I'm building a REST API based on [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)/[DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and PostgreSQL. I want all `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE` endpoints to follow the best practices and be **idempotent**. How can I ensure/verify that this is true?

Comment: How Django/DRF is involved in it? Take a look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-8.1.3

Comment: I mentioned django/drf in case there's any functionality there that deals with idempotency.

Comment: Not in core. You can implement X-Idempotency-Key header and Middleware for it.

Comment: There is a library for this, but not sure why it's incompatible with Django 3.x.x. I've asked the author to provide information so I can do a PR. https://github.com/yoyowallet/django-idempotency-key

Answer (score 4):

**I know it is too late to answer this question, but I would like to answer it for those others who might be interested.**

By default, `GET` and `DELETE` are idempotent since the only possible response states are either `404` or sending data, but not `PUT` or if we needed to make any POST request idempotent. for `PUT` the most common way is the validation of input data. Make sure that all the fields of the model(including `id`) are passed in unless the client receives `400 bad request` this way since even id is passed in no one can add unwanted records to the database. another way to be 100% sure everything is idempotent, is we may use cache to **store the request body and user's id as hash into cache server for enough amount of time**. something like this:

```
# in views.py
# for DRF
import hashlib

from django.core.cache import cache
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class IdempotentView(APIView):
     def put(self, req, pk, format=None):

         key = hashlib.blake2b(
                   f"{req.user.username}, {req.body},{pk}".encode("utf-8")
               ).hexdigest()
         is_cached = cache.get(key)

         if is_cached :
            return Response (req.body, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
         
         # preform the view commands then:
         
         expiary  = 60*60*3 # 3 hours 
         cache.set(key, 'True' , exp_date)

         return Response (data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: I would suggest using something like `hashlib.blake2b` rather than relying on `hash`, for the reduced chance of collisions.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the following post can shed a light on the topic: [Create or Update (with PUT) in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024781/create-or-update-with-put-in-django-rest-framework)

Quote:

```
class ResourceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This endpoint provides `create`, `retrieve`, `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Resource.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResourceSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            resource = Resource.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).first()
            if resource:
                return resource
            else:
                return Resource(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        else:
            return super(ResourceViewSet, self).get_object()
```

but more elegant solution which also checks for permissions - is https://gist.github.com/tomchristie/a2ace4577eff2c603b1b