# DRF Update Insert in ManytoMany, ForeignKey Relationship Models

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have six models, they are below:

```
class Certificate(DateTimeLog):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=255)


class Vacancy(DateTimeLog):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent_position = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                        related_name='sub_positions')


class Region(DateTimeLog):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class MaritalStatus(DateTimeLog):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Candidate(DateTimeLog):
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    marital_status = models.ForeignKey(MaritalStatus, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    certificate = models.ManyToManyField(Certificate, blank=True)


class Candidacy(DateTimeLog):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vacancy = models.ForeignKey(Vacancy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I want to handle, if **candidate** record exists(I am checking it with **pin**), then check and update Candidate related data. If a candidate does not exist create it.
After the candidate is created or updated assign it to the candidacy.
My Serializer looks like below:

```
class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    marital_status = MaritalStatusSerializer(required=False)
    certificate = CertificateSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        marital_status_data = validated_data.pop("marital_status")
        certificate_data = validated_data.pop("certificate")
        candidate = Candidate.objects.create(**validated_data)

        ms_o = MaritalStatus.objects.get(name=marital_status_data["name"])
        candidate.marital_status = ms_o

        for certificate in certificate_data:
            certificate_o = Certificate.objects.create(**certificate)
            candidate.certificate.add(certificate_o)

        candidate.save()
        return candidate

    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1


class CandidacySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    candidate = CandidateSerializer()
    vacancy = VacancySerializer()
    work_region = RegionSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        candidate_s = CandidateSerializer()
        candidate_data = validated_data.pop('candidate')

        vacancy_data = validated_data.pop('vacancy')
        work_region_data = validated_data.pop('work_region')

        vac_o = Vacancy.objects.get(name=vacancy_data['name'])
        wr_o = Region.objects.get(name=work_region_data['name'])
        candidate_o = candidate_s.create(validated_data=candidate_data)
        validated_data.update({
            'candidate': candidate_o,
            'vacancy': vac_o,
            'work_region': wr_o
        })
        candidacy = Candidacy.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return candidacy

    class Meta:
        model = Candidacy
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Currently, I am able to create it with the post request. Am I need to check it explicitly or it is possible to achieve it inside the serializer?

Comment: do you mean if the record is already in the database as in like a unique validator or..?

Comment: In your `CandidateSerializer.create` you can do: `candidate = Candidate.objects.update_or_create(pin=validated_data.get('pin'), defaults=validated_data)`

Comment: @BrianDestura when post I got 400(bad request) it says that candidate with this pin already exists

Comment: Can you show what code you used for this?

Comment: I am sorry not understand, could you please elaborate more, what do you mean by "code" exactly?

Comment: Please show the changes you have done that caused the `400(bad request)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use `update_or_create` in your `CandidateSerializer` like this:

```
class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    marital_status = MaritalStatusSerializer(required=False)
    certificate = CertificateSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        marital_status_data = validated_data.pop("marital_status")
        certificate_data = validated_data.pop("certificate")
        candidate, created = Candidate.objects.update_or_create(
            pin=validated_data['pin'],
            **validated_data
        )

        ms_o = MaritalStatus.objects.get(name=marital_status_data["name"])
        candidate.marital_status = ms_o

        for certificate in certificate_data:
            certificate_o = Certificate.objects.create(**certificate)
            candidate.certificate.add(certificate_o)

        candidate.save()
        return candidate

    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Secondly, you should not call the method `create()` directly. You have to use `save()` instead. You have to replace:

```
candidate_s = CandidateSerializer()
candidate_o = candidate_s.create(validated_data=candidate_data)
```

by

```
candidate_s = CandidateSerializer(data=candidate_data)
candidate_o = candidate_s.save()
```

You can read more about saving instances [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances).

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I will test it.

Answer (score 0):

so you have a more straightforward option. There is a function called get or create, which will check if the object exists and return it else make it.
[similar question can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026034/django-rest-framework-modelserializer-get-or-create-functionality)
[Another use of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41241630/8988796)
By the way, if this pin is sensitive, I recommend encrypting it.

Comment: I tried it, but not worked! same exception.

Comment: What version of the Django rest framework is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already made pin unique with

```
pin = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
```

there is no chance of having two similar pins. and now to check a candidate based on pin you will have to manually do something like this in your create method.

```
if Candidate.objects.filter(pin = revievedPinData):
    here candidate is already present so update the information information
    and again check if Canditate is in Candidacy or not
    first get the candidate object
    c = Candidate.objects.get(pin = revievedPinData)
    then
    if Candidacy.objects.filter(candidate = c):
       if true candidate is already assigned and the updated value of candidate will reflect here
    else: create the Candidacy with the current candidate and other values
else:
    if candidate is not there (from the given pin)
    create a new candidate
    aa = candidate.objects.create()
    create a new Candidacy with candidate aa
    Candidacy.objects.create(candidate=aa, **otherdata)
```

Comment: it is not getting errors in create method. Not worked! I got an exception from validations.

Comment: What exceptions from validators?

Comment: Are you getting error in candidate create, candidate update or candidancy create ?

Comment: candidate create

Comment: and what is the error ?

Comment: {
    "candidate": {
        "pin": [
            "candidate with this pin already exists."
        ]
    }
}

Comment: so if a candidate with that pin is already there, why are you creating a new candidate with the same pin ? just see whether that candidate is in Candidacy or not. If not create a new candidacy with the same candidate having this pin.

Comment: Check wheteher this -> **Candidate.objects.filter(pin = revievedPinData):** is returning true or false.